# How are "jumpers" used?

Tags: jumper

Two settings on a system I've got can be changed using jumpers. This is the connector and the pin description:

[image]
[image]

There seems to be three pins needed to choose between ON and OFF, but how? Do I set them to high/low in some pattern? The documentation is very sparse so I assume this is some standard interface, but I couldn't google it.

> 5.3 Jumpers description
>
> Please note that the two jumpers on the board are PTH (plated-through hole) type and should be easy to
>   mount/dismount.
>
> 5.3.1 TARGET jumper
>
> TARGET jumper controls the powering of the target board. If it is in position ON (check the diagram on the back of the
>   plastic cover) it will provide either 3.3V or 5V to the target board
>   (depending on the position of the POWER jumper) The default position
>   is OFF.

Comment: In the pictured example, it looks like the settings are "OFF" and "5V".

Comment: @PhilFrost Yep. When I asked the question, I had no idea how jumpers worked and didn't realise that the actual things that connect the wires were already there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(That looks like an AVR programmer)

The jumper is a tiny plug that connects two pins.

[image]

You put the jumper either on the left two pins or on the right two pins. The middle pin is a common pin.

[image]

In your case the jumpers are being used as a SPDT switch that can't be accidentally moved.

To change the selection, pull off the jumper and push it into the alternate position.

This applies to each group of three pins

Comment: Aha, thanks. Well spotted, it's an AVR-ISP-MKII.

Comment: It looks like the OFF and 5V pins are already connected. That can be seen in the photo, too. Is that what is meant by "default position"? Do I have to cut it before I connect a jumper?

Comment: Never mind, I get it! I didn't realise that there were _already_ jumpers on the pins, and that I can remove them.

Comment: No you don't need to cut anything, you just pull off a jumper and push it on in the other position. As I understand it, if your target board doesn't provide a voltage reference on the main connector, you have to tell the programmer what voltage to use for programming. I think the "off" position means the board doesn't provide a reference voltage, in which case the programmer uses the lower jumper position to decide what voltage to zap your AVR with.

Comment: "Do I have to cut it...": You just missed the opportunity to be the first person to actually cut a jumper instead of just unplugging it :)

Answer (score 1):

Jumpers are  metal clips that short circuit two pins. The pins select which parts of the circuit are connected.

Answer (score 1):

Jumpers are used in order to enable the user to change setting simply moving it.

The central pin is common, so if you want to set the device ON the jumper must stay in the first two pins, if you want to set the device OFF the jumper must stay in the last two pins. The same is true for the power supply (5V left, 3.3V right). In **every** case you must connect the jumper, otherwise the selection input is floating and it can't work correctly.

Comment: What do you mean by "in every case"? The documentation mentions default settings.

Comment: If you remove the jumper, for example, the power supply isn't connected both to 5V and 3.3V. So the device won't work. Without the jumper the input is floating.

Comment: Oh, I get it! the jumpers are already there!

Comment: Yes, default settings means the standard position of jumpers.